# Take back-ups of specific Stored Procedures, Views, Functions and Triggers using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, mssql-jdbc

Our team receives a patch file containing SQL object folders. These SQL object folders have SQL files pertaining to those objects. For example,

```
---patch123

-------StoredProcedure
------------abc_StoredProcedure.sql
------------def_StoredProcedure.sql

-------Functions
-------------abc_Functions.sql
-------------def_Functions.sql
```

I want to take backups of only these four SQL files and save them into a txt file which would be compressed in a zip file.

I have read the answer to this SO question by @Kin Shah, but `sys.sql_modules with sys.objects` will take the entire backup of all SPs, funcs, etc.

I want to be able to take a back up of specific set of files? Is it possible to do using T-SQL?

Based on @Dan Guzman's suggestion

[image]

Comment: You could extract source for an individual object just by adding a `WHERE` clause to the catalog view query you mentioned. Alternatively, you could use the [SMO Scripter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/scripting) with PowerShell or .NET language.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have used your suggestion `sys.sql_modules with sys.objects WHERE selectUsers_SP`, but i am getting `Incorrect syntax near 'sys'.` in SSMS. I am pretty new to mssql. It is obvious i am making a mistake

Comment: You didn't include the actual query you tried in the question but it should be like `SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.abc_StoredProcedure','U');`

Comment: @DanGuzman I have updated the question with screenshot. Did it take a backup? Will the output be blank? What is `U` in `N'dbo.abc_StoredProcedure','U'`?

Comment: The empty result set indicates the query was not run in the correct database or the proc doesn't exist in the database. Note the query will just return the definition; you will need to save the definition to a file manually. Consider using the SSMS scripting wizard to help you if you don't have .NET or PowerShell skills. Right-click on the  database in SSMS Object Explorer and select Tasks-->Generate Scripts and select one file per object.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have removed the U from (N'dbo.abc_StoredProcedure','U'), and now the definition is visible. Is an admin user login is required to execute this query? And will it work on views, triggers and functions apart from SPs? I am sorry for asking lot of questions :)

Comment: @KrisT, give it a try and you will know if it works or not